# Time complexity of Introduction to Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm learning the Introduction to Algorithms and I'm confused about the answers of exercises:

1. `10*log10` = O(`log n^2`)
   // I think it should be 10*log10 = Theta(log n^2)
2. `n^1.01` = Omega( `n* (log n)^2` )

   // I think should be `n^1.01` = O( `n* (log n)^2` )
3. `(log n)^log n` = Omega ( `n / log n` )

   // I think should be `(log n)^log n` = O ( `n / log n` )
4. `n*2^n` = O (`3^n`)

   // I don't know how to prove this.....

Is my thinking correct? I'm appreciating if you can provide with some proof of those four questions.

Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the things. Equality (=) in complexity theory must be read as "belongs to class" and not "equals". And then you have to cleary realize the meaning of Big-Oh notation (and other omegas and thetas...). For example, O(n) represents ALL functions that grow no faster than linear function. More formally, if f(n) = O(n) (reads "f(n) belongs to class O(n)"), there exists constant c such that for any n: f(n) < c*n. For instance both f(n) = n and f(n) = log(n) belong to O(n) (i.e., they grow no faster).

Let us consider one of your examples:

n*2^n = O(3^n).

In order to prove that we must find some constant c such that:

n*2^n < c * 3^n;

Some math:
n*2^n < c * 3^n => n < c * (1.5)^n;

You can easily see that, even for c=1 this holds, which proves the statement.
Again, be sure you understand the complexity terminology well.